# android = Подскажите почему при использование TextView закрывается приложение

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, сокет, activity

При использовании `in` и `out` в классе MainActivity приложение закрывается.
Если использовать их напрямую в методе `OnCreate ()` всё работает, но когда используется в потоках ничего не работает.

```
package com.example.clients;    
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView out;
    TextView in;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        out = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out);
        in = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.In);

    }
    Connection mSocket = new Connection();

    public void OnClickConnection(View view){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            mSocket.openConnect();

            }
        }).start();
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 while(true){
                 out.setText(mSocket.message());

             }}
         }).start();
    }
    public void OnClickDisconnection(View view){
         mSocket.closeConnect();

    }
    public void OnRecieve(View view){
        mSocket.Recieve(in.getText().toString());
    }


}
```

Класс Connection:

```
package com.example.clients;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
public class Connection {

    private String IpAdd = "25.31.107.195";
    Toast toast;
    private int port = 6988;
    private Socket socket;
    public Connection(){}

    public void openConnect(){
       closeConnect();
        try{
            socket = new Socket(IpAdd,port);
        }catch(IOException e){}

    }
    public void closeConnect() {
        if ((socket != null)&&(!socket.isClosed())){
            try {
                socket.close();
            }catch(IOException e){}

        }

    }
    public String message(){
        String msg=null;
              try {
            BufferedReader in;
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
          msg = in.readLine();
        }catch(IOException e){}

        return msg;
    }
    public void Recieve(String msg) {
        byte[] value = msg.getBytes();
        try {
            socket.getOutputStream().write(value);
            socket.getOutputStream().flush();
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }


}
```

Приложение должно принимать данные от сервера и отправлять их ему.
Надеюсь проблему объяснил хорошо и понятно.

Comment: В других потоках, кроме главного доступа к Uİ (`TextView`) нет. Доступ можно получить через Handler.post(...), экземпляр которого был создан в основном потоке. А вообще лучше прикладывать стэктрейс ошибки для более точных ответов

Comment: Из фоновых потоков нельзя менять UI. Для Вашей задачи нужен [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) . Можете почитать этот урок: [startandroid.ru/Урок 80. Handler. Немного теории. Наглядный пример использования](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/143-urok-80-handler-nemnogo-teorii-nagljadnyj-primer-ispolzovanija.html) - там как раз такая проблема решается хэндлером.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает